# how to check multiple element for the same event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

same behavior to multiple elements.

// html

```
<div id="">
<input type="hidden" value="1258" /> value of user id to make friend
</div> 
<div id="">
<input type="hidden" value="2595" />
</div>
<div id="">
<input type="hidden" value="2563" />
</div>
```

now i want to check which div to clicked to add friend and to take the hidden value and send it to server using this code

```
$().click(function(){
 $x=$("hidden").value(); // the value is friendID
//then send $x to the server using Ajax
});
```

I'v tried using it like this

```
$("#div1,#div2,#div3").click(function(){
 $x=$("hidden").value(); // the value is friendID
//then send $x to the server using Ajax
});
```

but i had more element the code grow and it's not dynamic, also the same thing if i want to make behavior to like button ,i have multiple like button how should i know which  post and which like

Answer (score 4):

Your selectors are all wrong. The `div` elements do not have any `id` attributes, so selecting them as you are will not work. Secondly, you want to use `:hidden` or `input[type="hidden"]` to select the hidden inputs. Finally, to get the value of a form element, use `val()`, not `value()`.

If you want to make this dynamic, so the code will work for `x` number of `div` elements, use a `class` to identify them and then `this` within the handler to access the element that raised the event, like this:

```
<div class="foo">
    <input type="hidden" value="1258" /> value of user id to make friend
</div> 
<div class="foo">
    <input type="hidden" value="2595" />
</div>
<div class="foo">
    <input type="hidden" value="2563" />
</div>
```

```js
$('.foo').click(function(){
    x = $(this).find('input[type="hidden"]').val(); 
    alert(x)
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ac7Dw/)

Answer (score -1):

try

```
<div id="div1">
<input type="hidden" value="1258" /> value of user id to make friend
</div>


$("[id^=div]").click(function() {
   $x=$(this).find("[type=hidden]").val();
});
```

or

```
<div class="classSelector">
    <input type="hidden" value="1258" /> value of user id to make friend
    </div>

 $(".classSelector").click(function() {
       $x=$(this).find("[type=hidden]").val();
    });
```

Comment: did you use **==** on purpose??

Comment: @TJ it was just a typo.. you could have edited that for me instead of casting a down vote.. :(

Comment: Well, it's not just a typo... still there's problem with the answer… there are no `id`'s like `div1, div2` etc in OP's html…

Comment: @TJ OP just given a sample like that, and i just inherited it and answered him, if i do anything overwhelmingly as you said then people will say `who the retard/moron given this suggestion to you for making this.?`

Comment: Your answer is still wrong. OP's html doesn't have divs matching your selector. If your answer requires any modification to OP's html, you've to explicitly mention it. Take [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23927373/2333214) for e.g.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54696/discussion-between-manishankar-and-t-j).